# How to make a array value as array key of whole array in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
$given_array=array (0 => array ('name' => 'Title','type' => 'Dropdown List',),1 => array ('name' => 'Size','type' => 'Color or custom image swatch');
$required_array=array ('Title' => array ('name' => 'Title','type' => 'Dropdown List',),'Size' => array ('name' => 'Size','type' => 'Color or custom image swatch');
```

Comment: $required_array = array_column($given_array, null, 'name');

Answer (score 0):

A simple `foreach()` will do the trick for you,

```
$required_array = [];
foreach($given_array as $key=>$value){
    $required_array[$value['name']] = $value;
}

print_r($required_array);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/VTgXd